# How to lock object rotation along a path

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

I'm a little new to Blender and I have an object traveling along a path. However, I need the object to stay locked in a specific orientation while it traverses the path from start to finish. Think of a camera dolly except on a curve.

In Top view, create a S-shaped 2d curve from left to right (say about X axis). Create an cube object with a more vertical aspect ratio (oriented in Y axis, top is pointing to +Y). Add Follow path (if that's the best choice) to the cube in order to travel along the 2D curve.

In the top view, I would like the cube to remain in it's original +Y orientation (aligned parallel to the Y axis), yet animate along the 2D curve from start point to end point of the path. No matter what options I set in either the Follow Path constraint or on the object, the object always wants to snap the original Y axis of the object normal to the curve.

Answer (score 4):

- Select your path / curve object
- Go to *Properties Editor > Object data*
- Find the *Path Animation* panel
- Untick **Follow** to disable the rotation along path
  [image: Curve Path Animation don't follow]

Comment: Thanks CoDEmanX- I actually tried this simultaneously to your answer. I also added a Limit Rotation constraint on all X Y and Z axiis. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix the issue as suggested by CodeManX, but it didn't work for me.

Instead, I fixed the issue by adjusting the `Twist Method`, and setting it to `Z-Up` (thanks for pointing me in the right direction!).

[image: Screenshot showing the Object Data Properties tab, with the Twist Method encircled.]